# This is my HTTP POST request but I got connection as successfull. It shows response is null. How to rectify this?

Tags: ios, json, http

MY HTTP POST request code:
This url runs from the localhost:

```
NSMutableURLRequest  *  request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"xxx"]];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

[request setValue:@"application/json; charset= utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

NSString * stringdata = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{'wk_time':{'user':{'id':1,'name':'xxx'},'startday':'2016-01-03','status':'New','total':3.0,'time_entries':[{'id':221,'project':{'id':2,'name':'xxx'},'issue':{'id':5},'user':{'id':1,'name':'xxx'},'activity':{'id':8,'name':'Design'},'hours':3.0,'spent_on':'2016-01-03','custom_fields':[{'id':4,'name':'test'},{'id':6,'name':'cfBoolean'},{'id':7,'name':'cfInt'},{'id':8,'name':'cfDate'},{'id':9,'name':'cfLongText'},{'id':10,'name':'cfUser'},{'id':11,'name':'cftext'}]}]}"];

NSData *requestbody = [stringdata dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
request.HTTPBody = requestbody;

NSURLConnection *conn1 = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

NSLog(@ "%@",response);

if (conn1)
{
NSLog(@"success");
}
else
{
NSLog(@"unsucess");
}
```

In this piece of code, I am getting success message, but the response is null. I'm trying to update the values through url POST but no data gets updated. And When I post the same data through test api it gets updated. As I'm new to this i Don't know what is wrong with this code? Need guidance.

Comment: You are getting success as your if condition is checking whether `conn1` object has memory or not. which ofcrs has. So as soon as you hit the if condition it is returning YES but there is no response as the response hasnt been completed or rather fetched from the backend yet. 
You should look into HTTP method calls with blocks and delegates more to understand the concept of it. 
You can also use `AFNetworking` which is a brilliant library for network calls and does the job more easily

Comment: Use ```[NSURLSession dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:]```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 NSDictionary *parameters = @{
                             @"token": _token.text,
                             @"userId": _userId.text
                             };

NSString *url = [baseUrl stringByAppendingString:@"/v1/users/confirm-signup"];
NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];

NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
NSString *jsonStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL  cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:20.0f];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[theRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[theRequest setValue:@"application/json; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody:[jsonStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:theRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *responseCode, NSData *responseData, NSError *responseError) {
    if ([responseData length] > 0 && responseError == nil){

        }
    }else if ([responseData length] == 0 && responseError == nil){

    }else if (responseError != nil && responseError.code == NSURLErrorTimedOut){

    }else if (responseError != nil){

    }
}];
```

try these piece of code it might help you

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is not valid. You should be using `"` instead of `'`. Also, I think the braces don't quite match up. Run it through http://jsonlint.com and see. I'd suggest using dictionary/array literals (that way, the compiler will tell you if you've mismatched any closing braces/brackets) and then use `NSJSONSerialization` to build the JSON. By using `NSJSONSerialization`, it makes sure your JSON is well formatted.

You're also starting the connection twice, once with `sendSynchronousRequest` and once with `initWithRequest`. Do one or the other, but not both. Or, better, use `NSURLSession` (because `NSURLConnection` is now deprecated).

Thus, pulling this all together, you want something like:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"xxx"]];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

[request setValue: @"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"wk_time": @{@"user": @{@"id": @1, @"name": @"xxx"}, @"startday": @"2016-01-03", @"status": @"New", @"total": @3.0, @"time_entries": @[@{@"id": @221, @"project": @{@"id": @2, @"name": @"xxx"}, @"issue": @{@"id": @5}, @"user": @{@"id": @1, @"name": @"xxx"}, @"activity": @{@"id": @8, @"name": @"Design"}, @"hours": @3.0, @"spent_on": @"2016-01-03", @"custom_fields": @[@{@"id": @4, @"name": @"test"}, @{@"id": @6, @"name": @"cfBoolean"}, @{@"id": @7, @"name": @"cfInt"}, @{@"id": @8, @"name": @"cfDate"}, @{@"id": @9, @"name": @"cfLongText"}, @{@"id": @10, @"name": @"cfUser"}, @{@"id": @11, @"name": @"cftext"}]}]}};

NSError *jsonError;
NSData *requestbody = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:0 error:&jsonError];
NSAssert(requestbody, @"JSON failed: %@", jsonError);
request.HTTPBody = requestbody;

// if you want to see what well-formed JSON looks like, check out:
//
// NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:requestbody encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

NSURLSessionTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"request failed: %@", error);
        return;
    }

    if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
        NSInteger statusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];
        if (statusCode != 200) {
            NSLog(@"Status code should be 200, but is %ld", (long)statusCode);
        }
    }

    // process `data` here, for example, if JSON:

    NSError *parseError;
    NSDictionary *responseObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError];
    if (!responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"parsing error: %@", parseError);
        NSLog(@"resultString = %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"resultObject = %@", responseObject);
    }
}];
[task resume];

// do not use `data` here, because the above happens asynchronously
```

Comment: Well, if you put `"` in `NSString`, you'll have to escape it with backslash. But you shouldn't build JSON string manually at all. But `'` is not valid quote character in JSON.

Comment: sir my response is something like successfully update or authentication required..how to see the response sir

Comment: As long as you don't fix your basic problems as Rob says, there is no point looking at any error messages.

Comment: @Rob it hits the request but the response is null only.where is the problem.i put your edited code only. is it mandate to pass the username and password on headers.

Comment: it runs upto nsurlsession after it gets out of loop ....whether the data passing format is not right or any other issue?

Comment: @Rob if it is not make a request i will get error message but it doesn't show error....what might be the problem?

Comment: @catherine007 - You are receiving neither error nor successful response? That's pretty curious. You'd expect _something_. One approach for diagnosing is to watch the request/response with [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com) and see what's really coming back. FYI, I've added some `statusCode` diagnostics to my above code snippet. Re adding userid/password, that's a question of what your server requires, so I cannot answer that question, but you'd expect some error message indicating the problem if the server code was written properly.

Comment: yes it requires login only .....how to pass the username and password with in this code..sir if username=admin and password = admin

Comment: how to pass the username and password in headers.

Comment: @Rob I  have the error message  like this in my log    "Current user: anonymous
Filter chain halted as :require_login rendered or redirected
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms) " so i thought it's a authentication required.so i put the code like this [request setValue:@"admin" forHTTPHeaderField:@"username"];
[request setValue:@"admin" forHTTPHeaderField:@"password"];

Comment: then i tried some thing like this NSString * authstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username%@:password%@",@"admin",@"admin"];
NSData * authdata = [authstring dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString  * authvalue =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"basic %@",[authdata base64Encoding]];
[request setValue: @"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:authvalue  forHTTPHeaderField: @"Authorization"]; but the same error message occurs. so format is not correct for sending userbname and password.

Comment: How to alter the execution of methods.......i have didrowselectatindexpath delegate method and -(void) issuedetails in this.i have to execute the didrowselectatindexpath first then followed by issuedetails. how to do this?

Comment: @catherine007 I don't understand your question. I'd suggest you post a new question on that including (a) what `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` looks like; (b) a description how that behaves; and (c) a description of how you want it to behave. Likewise, if you're still having authorization problems, post another question on that.

Comment: @Rob sir take a look at tis question sir..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34986880/how-to-create-the-mutable-dictionary-dynamically-for-this-json-response-in-ios/34987252?noredirect=1#comment57703712_34987252