# How to Create the Mutable Dictionary Dynamically For this Json Response in IOS

Tags: ios, json, dictionary

This is my JSON Response 1 for the time entry Spent_on:"2015-12-27"

```
{
    "A": {
        "user": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "B"
        },
        "startday": "2015-12-27",
        "status": "New",
        "total": 2,
        "time_entries": [{
            "id": 768,
            "project": {
                "id": 8,
                "name": "C"
            },
            "user": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "B"
            },
            "activity": {
                "id": 8,
                "name": "D"
            },
            "hours": 2,
            "comments": "",
            "spent_on": "2015-12-27"
        }]
    }
}
```

I had created the dictionary format like this to do post operation:

```
NSDictionary * response =@{@"A": @{@"user": @{@"id": @1,@"name": @"B"},@"startday@": @"2015-12-27",@"status@": @"New",@"total@": 2,@"time_entries@": [{@"id@": 768,@"project@": {@"id@": 8,@"name": @"C"},@"user": {@"id": 1,@"name": @"B"},@"activity": {@"id": 8,@"name": @"D"},@"hours": 2,@"comments": @"",@"spent_on": @"2015-12-27"}]}};
```

This is my JSON response 2 for time entry Spent_on:"2015-12-27" and "2015-12-28"

```
{
    "A": {
        "user": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "B"
        },
        "startday": "2015-12-27",
        "status": "New",
        "total": 6,
        "time_entries": [{
            "id": 768,
            "project": {
                "id": 8,
                "name": "C"
            },
            "user": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "B"
            },
            "activity": {
                "id": 8,
                "name": "D"
            },
            "hours": 2,
            "comments": "",
            "spent_on": "2015-12-27"
        }, {
            "id": 775,
            "project": {
                "id": 8,
                "name": "C"
            },
            "user": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "B"
            },
            "activity": {
                "id": 8,
                "name": "D"
            },
            "hours": 4,
            "comments": "",
            "spent_on": "2015-12-28"
        }]
    }
}
```

The json response 2 having one more time_entry id,hours,spent_on than json response1.similarly, for every new hours entry for every new date(spent_on).A new time entry id will generate and also Response length will increase.

So, How to create the mutable dictionary or dictionary for above response and also if the different hours and different date will occur(example for one full week).for that how to create dictionary for it?Else any other way to do this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Rob Sir please take a look and give idea sir...

Comment: @downvoter for what ?

Comment: @downvoter what's wrong with this question? if you don't know ...just keep idle...others answer will help to do it...

Comment: any one help me please.

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but perhaps they didn't think you didn't demonstrate much research effort. You may forestall these down votes in the future if you outline what you tried and/or what research you've done. Also, the large, unformatted JSON samples weren't entirely clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
char* jsonCStr = "{             \
\"A\": {                          \
    \"user\": {                   \
        \"id\": 1,                \
        \"name\": \"B\"             \
    },                          \
    \"startday\": \"2015-12-27\",   \
    \"status\": \"New\",            \
    \"total\": 2,                 \
    \"time_entries\": [           \
    {                           \
        \"id\": 768,              \
        \"project\": {            \
            \"id\": 8,            \
            \"name\": \"C\"         \
        },                      \
        \"user\": {               \
            \"id\": 1,            \
            \"name\": \"B\"         \
        },                      \
        \"activity\": {           \
            \"id\": 8,            \
            \"name\": \"D\"         \
        },                      \
        \"hours\": 2,             \
        \"comments\": \"\",         \
        \"spent_on\": \"2015-12-27\"\
    }                           \
                     ]          \
    }                           \
}";

NSString* jsonStr = [NSString stringWithCString:jsonCStr encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData* jsonData = [jsonStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary* dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
```

Comment: i tried this creating a string is not an wise idea....and also that response have to concatenated...if the length f the response is increasing quite difficult to concatenation,if some error occurs we couldn't find where exactly it occurs. i already tried this if we create manually it works..but we create a string with concatenation...it throws error.it won't post via rest api.that's why i used dictionary

Comment: do you look at that i asked dictionary format for json response 2 but you created  string for json response 1....

Comment: this operation fit json response 2.Usually,we create an dictionary or array for  each response.         I dont understand the words meaning "if the length f the response is increasing quite difficult to concatenation".     if you worry about the response is too long,that is not your problem,it occurs because that the server interface is not reasonable.you should not    use just one interface to response all infomation

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34848941/how-to-rectify-this-string-format-error-in-ios ...i created already like this...but i didn't get proper response..so then only i create dictionary....

Comment: any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You ask:

> So, How to create the mutable dictionary or dictionary for above response?

When you parse it with `JSONObjectWithData`, use `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` option. That will result in mutable dictionarys/arrays.

```
NSError *error;
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

> also if the different hours and different date will occur(example for one full week).for that how to create dictionary for it?

So, get a reference to that the mutable array of time entries:

```
NSMutableArray *timeEntries = dictionary[@"A"][@"time_entries"];
```

And then add whatever you want for the new date:

```
[timeEntries addObject:@{@"id":       @768,
                         @"project":  @{@"id": @8, @"name": @"C"},
                         @"user":     @{@"id": @1, @"name": @"B"},
                         @"activity": @{@"id": @8, @"name": @"D"},
                         @"hours":    @2,
                         @"comments": @"",
                         @"spent_on": @"2015-12-29"}];
```

Just repeat (or loop) as necessary.

Comment: sir is it possible to create template for left hand side of json response sir. example like id:project{id: if i create like this. i will get values dynamically.then i can post dynamically.

Comment: In the above response how to get the time_entries id  i do like this _time_entryid= [[[dictionary objectforkey@"wk_time] objectforkey@"time_entries"]objectforkey:@"id"]; but it shows null sir. how to get that id .